# How to deploy Lambda using terraform created by CDKTF?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-cdk, terraform-cdk

I am following this guide from hashicorp https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/cdktf/cdktf-assets-stacks-lambda

It uses s3 for lambda deployment package

```
// Create Lambda executable
    const asset = new TerraformAsset(this, "lambda-asset", {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.path),
      type: AssetType.ARCHIVE, // if left empty it infers directory and file
    });

    // Create unique S3 bucket that hosts Lambda executable
    const bucket = new aws.s3Bucket.S3Bucket(this, "bucket", {
      bucketPrefix: `learn-cdktf-${name}`,
    });

    // Upload Lambda zip file to newly created S3 bucket
    const lambdaArchive = new aws.s3Object.S3Object(this, "lambda-archive", {
      bucket: bucket.bucket,
      key: `${config.version}/${asset.fileName}`,
      source: asset.path, // returns a posix path
    });
 
// Create Lambda function
const lambdaFunc = new aws.lambdaFunction.LambdaFunction(this, "learn-cdktf-lambda", {
  functionName: `learn-cdktf-${name}-${pet.id}`,
  s3Bucket: bucket.bucket,
  s3Key: lambdaArchive.key,
  handler: config.handler,
  runtime: config.runtime,
  role: role.arn
});
```

I have figured out a way to use the synthesised code from cdktf ( cdktf.json) in my existing terraform project, however, s3 bucket object generated uses a source which is a posit suffix

```
"aws_s3_object": {
      "lambda-archive": {
        "//": {
          "metadata": {
            "path": "lambda-hello-world/lambda-archive",
            "uniqueId": "lambda-archive"
          }
        },
        "bucket": "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket}",
        "key": "v0.0.2/archive.zip",
        "source": "assets/lambda-asset/ABCDEDGHIJKLAMN000006786986/archive.zip"
      }
    },
```

When I try to use terraform apply with cdktf.json it says source not found, how do I deal with this, is there a way to deploy lambda with cdktf without s3 ?

Comment: Should this `new aws.s3Object.S3Object` be `new aws.S3BucketObject`?

Comment: I am using this code from haschicorp tutorial, tried to change, it is showing some typescript errors.

Comment: Ah, ok, because it seems the code in the repo was updated, but the page shows the second syntax.

Comment: As of now this works, if I use cdktf deploy, but I want to fix this assets error, if I am I can do this I can use it in my existing terraform or do you have any idea on how to use typescript lambda with terraform

Comment: So the path to the Lambda zip is the issue?

Comment: Yes, when I try terraform apply with this cdktf.json its not able to find this zip file.

Comment: and it exists in that `lambda-hello-world/lambda-archive` subpath without a `.zip` extension?

Comment: That is the problem, I think CDKTF is determining that at runtime, because I cannot see any file being generated in my local files

Answer (score 0):

This here worked well for me. But is is using TypeScript https://github.com/cdktf/cdktf-integration-serverless-example/blob/main/lib/nodejs-function.ts

I created an example repo how it could look like in a repo https://github.com/mmuller88/cdktf-lambda .

Comment: I cant see, how are you integrating this with your existing terraform?

Comment: Good question. I added an example repo.

Comment: You didn't; understood my question problem is not with cdktf, problem is how to use synthesised code generated with cdktf in my existing terraform code

Answer (score 0):

If your Lambda code is stored locally, you can use the `filename` argument to deploy a Lambda function from Terraform/CDKTF using the local artifact without using S3:

> Once you have created your deployment package you can specify it either directly as a local file (using the filename argument) or indirectly via Amazon S3 (using the s3_bucket, s3_key and s3_object_version arguments). When providing the deployment package via S3 it may be useful to use the aws_s3_object resource to upload it.

Otherwise, you can try using an absolute path when creating the asset

> Assets support both absolute and relative paths. Relative paths are always considered to be relative to your project's cdktf.json file.