# CDK: How to use/import s3 defined in one stack to another stack (in a different file)?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to define s3 bucket in one stack and use that bucket in another stack. Both the stack are in different files. How to access `bucket.ts`'s s3 bucket in `pipeline.ts` bucket.

I am looking for an answer which explains the concept so that I repeat it for other stacks too.

bucket.ts

```js
    import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3';
    import { Construct } from 'constructs';
    
    export class PipelineSourceBucket extends cdk.Stack {
        constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    
            super(scope, id, props);
    
            const sourceBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'pipelineSourceBucket', {
                versioned: true, // a Bucket used as a source in CodePipeline must be versioned
            });
        }
    }
```

pipeline.ts

```js
    import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import { Construct } from 'constructs';
    import * as codepipeline from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline';
    import * as codepipeline_actions from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions';
    
    
    export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    
        super(scope, id, props);
    
        const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'CodePipeline', {
          pipelineName: 'jatin-ci-cd',
          crossAccountKeys: false, // not required as it wont be cross account deployment
        })
        const sourceAction = new codepipeline_actions.S3SourceAction({
          actionName: 'S3Source',
          bucket: sourceBucket,  //how to access the bucket from other stack?
          bucketKey: 'path/to/file.zip',
          output: sourceOutput,
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: What are the permissions associated with the bucket and the pipeline?

Comment: by access I didnt meant iam permissions I am how to import, I will fix it. Also Marcin if you can take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74740782/how-to-deploy-lambda-using-terraform-created-by-cdktf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws-cdk-examples` repo has several [multi-stack examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/ecs/cross-stack-load-balancer/) demonstrating the pattern of passing variables from one construct class to another.  The steps are:

The dependency producer declares a [public field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructors) to export a reference.

```js
export class PipelineSourceBucket extends cdk.Stack {
    readonly sourceBucket: s3.Bucket

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        this.sourceBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'pipelineSourceBucket');
    }
}
```

The dependency consumer requires a bucket in its props.

```js
interface PipelineStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
    bucket: s3.Bucket
}
```

Instantiate both in `app.ts` and pass the bucket variable from the produer to the consumer:

```js
const { sourceBucket } = new PipelineSourceBucket(app, "SourceStack", {...etc})

new PipelieStack(app, "PipelineStack", {bucket: sourceBucket, ...etc})
```

Behind the scenes, the CDK will synth this dependency as CloudFormation import and export [cross-stack references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html).

Comment: I figured it out and this was the same approach I tool, thank you for explaining it so beautifully.